# Mysql - Voting once per Day

Tags: php, mysql

I have an entry where users can vote once per day. I''m saving this in my database.
Now I need to check, if the user is allowed to vote on this entry again (after one day).

So far I got this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM entries e
WHERE e.voterID =1
AND e.pID =1
AND e.date < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 1 
DAY
```

But this doesn't work to well, when in the DB there are more entries for the voter and pid. A voter can vote multiples times for the same entry.
  if there are more entries for the same user and the same projects, count(*) fives me a value more then 1. etc.

How do I check if the user is allowed to vote again properly?
Thanks.

Comment: search for datediff() function

Comment: yeah, but I need to check it for the latest entry, or not?

Comment: by after one day do you mean 24 hours or on the next day, ie they could vote at 11pm then 2am

Comment: sure, something like DATEDIFF(NOW(),max(e.date))>1

Comment: 24 hours! Sorry. If a users votes today: 11-04-2013 10:00:00 he is not alloed to vote before 11-05-2013 10:00:00 for the same entry

Comment: Why do you need to *check* anything. Just make sure there's a UNIQUE key on (voterid,date)

Comment: how does that help me?

Comment: @Marek123 comment off Strawberry is correct best and easy way to handle this with an INSERT from the PHP side and you should fetch the 1062 error when an duplicated is found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the present user vote for the present pID in the most recent 24 hours?  If so, the `votecount` result in this query will be more than zero.

```
 SELECT count(*) AS votecount
   FROM entries AS e
  WHERE e.voterID = 1
    AND e.pID = 1
    AND e.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Notice the `>=` comparison for the date. Your sample code says `<`.

You will need a compound index on (voterID, pID, date) when you need this query to run efficiently on a large table.